# What are the ideal tools to analyze sql scripts?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a huge ETL script that I am planning to understand. Are there any visual tools that can help me understand it more easily? I am using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284255/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool, [SQL Enlight](http://ubitsoft.com/products/sqlenlight/sqlenlight.php), may help you:

For example, see the section "Summarize T-SQL script" of [this URL](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/971738db-affa-4243-a1bc-5679722f54ec).

Unfortunately, its not a free product, but they do offer a free trial.